# ksql - is it possible to create stream from multiple topics and get full event payload?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

We have a requirement of listening on multiple topics and look for specific field in each topic's event. Each topic event is in json format and is gauranteed to have few fixed fields in json format. Need to filter events from all these multiple topics and look for a specific field in each event payload. If this field value matches certain format, then send those events from different topic to one fixed topic which can be further processed by another consumer.

Was looking if ksql can help in this scenario - we create a stream from multiple topics and filter data based on fixed column in ksql stream and push it to new topic.
The question I have is:
1) Is it possible to create a ksql stream from multiple topics?
2) Is it possible to get topic's complete event payload as one column in ksql stream?

On high level, (with wrong ksql syntax), I am looking for something like

```
CREATE STREAM my_all_topics (myFixedFiedl1 varchar, eventPayload varchar) WITH (value_format = 'json', kafka_topic_LIST='topic1, topic2, topic3');

CREATE STREAM mytopic_stream (myFixedFiedl1 varchar, eventPayload varchar) with (kafka_topic='my-final-topic-name', value_format='json')
as select myFixedField1, eventPayload from my_all_topics where myFixedField1 like 'myprefix%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it quite how you want—a KSQL `STREAM` is sourced from one and only one Kafka topic.

*But* you could use KSQL's `INSERT INTO` feature to achieve what you want.

1. Model your source topics:

   ```
   CREATE STREAM source_a (myFixedField1 varchar, eventPayload varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='topic_a', value_format='json')
   CREATE STREAM source_b (myFixedField1 varchar, eventPayload varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='topic_b', value_format='json')
   CREATE STREAM source_c (myFixedField1 varchar, eventPayload varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='topic_c', value_format='json')
   ```
2. Create the target topic, based on the first source topic:

   ```
   CREATE STREAM mytopic_stream (myFixedField1 varchar, eventPayload varchar) AS SELECT myFixedField1, eventPayload from source_a where myFixedField1 like 'myprefix%';
   ```
3. Specify insertion to the target topic from the remaining source topics:

   ```
   INSERT INTO mytopic_stream SELECT myFixedField1, eventPayload from source_b where myFixedField1 like 'myprefix%';
   INSERT INTO mytopic_stream SELECT myFixedField1, eventPayload from source_c where myFixedField1 like 'myprefix%';
   ```

See also

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z508VDdtp_M
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/basics-local.html#insert-into

Comment: Thanks Robin, will explore this option. Is it possible to get complete event payload as one column/field in stream? Put the complete event payload as string in one column

Comment: Depends on your source data. _Probably_, but I'd not like to say for sure. Can you share a sample of your data in the original question?

Comment: event format is having json structure. json contains multiple fields, few fields are fixed like eventId and type and always present in event. My main filtering logic depends if type is of certain format, I don't care about other fields but based on these fields, I will want to pass full payload to another topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain, but it seems you would be able to combine streams with a `JOIN`.

```
CREATE STREAM mytopic_stream AS
    SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
    FROM stream_A A
        JOIN stream_B B ON A.key = B.key_for_A
        JOIN stream_C C ON A.key = B.key_for_A
```

If you haven't already registered the Kafka topics with KSQL then you will have to take care of that step first.

Comment: That's right. Topic is the persistence layer of stream or table. I believe it was created before that. Or you can use Create stream and specify an existing topic name, then the topic will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume your data from multiple topics and send to a common topic, as to a collector and then process the stream as usual, Just take care of the compatibility of key and value types.